# What is RavenDB's default order of the results received when the Load function is used?

Tags: ravendb

If I execute following query: **session.Load(1, 2, 3).ToList();** can I assume that my documents in my list will also be returned with the same order as in my query **(1, 2,3)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be returned in the same order that you gave it.